# MySQL 'Group' syntax error when no Group statement?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to run the below script against MySQL server but I get the error:

`ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 28: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Group' at line 1`

Here's the sql script:

```
/* Remove old indexes */
USE production;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS DropIndexes;  
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE DropIndexes()
BEGIN
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE tbl, idx VARCHAR(1000);
  DECLARE index_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT TABLE_NAME, INDEX_NAME FROM information_schema.statistics WHERE table_schema =  'production' AND INDEX_NAME LIKE  'ix_%';
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

  OPEN index_cursor;

  read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH index_cursor INTO tbl, idx;
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
    SET @s = CONCAT('DROP INDEX ',idx,' ON ',tbl); 
    PREPARE stmt1 FROM @s; 
    EXECUTE stmt1; 
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1; 
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE index_cursor;
END//
DELIMITER ;
CALL DropIndexes();
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS DropIndexes;
```

Given the error makes no sense with no 'Group' statement I have no idea what the problem is.

Comment: Maybe you have an index named `group`. You need to escape reserved words like `group` with backticks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must be your Table name selected from the statistics table. To get it accepted enclose it in back-ticks. And though not required on your index name ( because it starts with `ix_` ), better you practice using the back-ticks.

```
SET @s = CONCAT( 'DROP INDEX `' , idx, '` ON `', tbl, '`' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have an index or table named `group`. You need to escape reserved words like `group` with backticks. Try

```
 SET @s = CONCAT('DROP INDEX `',idx,'` ON `',tbl,'`');
```

Comment: Suggest you further `REPLACE(idx, '\`', '\`\`')` (and similarly for `tbl`) to escape any (albeit unlikely) backticks in the respective object names.